# how to solve date matching in php mysql website?

Tags: php, mysql, date, web

So here is the thing I get dates from users from select tags like this:

```
<select>

<?php

  for($i=date('m'); $i>=0; $i--){

 echo "<option>".$i."</option>";

 }

  ?>

</select>
```

Now what this does is give 05 as first option 4,3,2,1 as next options, I want 04,03,02,01 as all options.

**How can I do that?**

Also I am running a sql query that deletes rows by matching dates.

So the date selected by user comes as `2013-5-18`(without zero) but the date in database is `2013-05-18` (with zero), so the dates don't match and the query is unable to delete the row.

Also can I change the way date is stored in a database?

I store date as `2013-5-18`(without zero) and it automatically gets stores as `2013-05-18` (with zero).

Any other thing that will just help me to match the dates so I can run the delete query?

Comment: for($i=date('m'); $i>=0; $i++) ! Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded ????????? look at your for loop once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
echo "< option>".sprintf("%02d", $i)."< /option>";
```

[sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) will format your number to have a preceding 0 when required.

What you're seeing is `date('m')` properly returning the value 05 for the first month. However when you add 1 to it (`$i++`) it's being cast to an integer, so the next value is 6. I might presume your actual code uses `$i--`, as this presently looks a lot like an infinite loop.

You might also consider handling the formatting when you build the query, rather than on form presentation. `$month = sprintf("%02d", $_POST['month']);` rather than relying on the client to pass it forward nicely.